# Is there a way to get all of the specific paragraphs from each element?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take all of the paragraphs from the given website and print them in the console.
So far my code can take all of divs which contain the paragraphs.
When I tried writing a loop which takes each element of final_text it only outputs the first paragraph.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.vanityfair.com/style/society/2014/06/monica-lewinsky-humiliation-culture"

source = requests.get(url)

source_html = source.text

soup_html = BeautifulSoup(source_html, "lxml")

soup_html.prettify()

final_text = soup_html.find_all("div", class_="grid--item body body__container article__body grid-layout__content")

for string in final_text:
    print(string)

#  The code finds all the the text; yet each element contains multiple paragraphs
#  Trying to convert these elements using .p only returns the first paragraph of each element
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to print all the paragraphs from that specific div. Then you need to `find_all` paragraphs from that div.

Replace this

```
final_text = soup_html.find_all("div", class_="grid--item body body__container article__body grid-layout__content")

for string in final_text:
    print(string)
```

with

```
# Just get the content inside this div
final_text = soup_html.find("div", class_="grid--item body body__container article__body grid-layout__content")

# Now get all the paragraphs from the div
final_text = final_text.find_all("p")
```

Implmentation:
https://repl.it/@ManishSundriyal/FittingThoughtfulScreencast

Note: this will only get all the paragraphs from `<div class_="grid--item body body__container article__body grid-layout__content">...</div>`
If you need paragraphs from the whole page then use the root div.

Comment: I get this error message:  

"ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: No, I meant to use find() for div instead of find_all.
here is the implementation link, it's working fine.
https://repl.it/@ManishSundriyal/FittingThoughtfulScreencast